# my clear inputs button calls handleSubmit() function and not Reset() function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

When I click on the "Clear" button, the handleSubmit function is called instead of the Reset function

my code:

(with

```
Reset(e){
e.preventDefault()
}
```

doesn't work either)

```
function Reset() {
    setName('')
    setUsername('')
    setPhone('')
    setEmail('')
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} action="" style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '1rem'}} autoComplete="off">
...
inputs
...
    <Button onClick={Reset} text="Limpar"/>
    <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}/>
</form>
```

Comment: Idk much about forms but I do believe that ```<Button onClick={Reset()}``` should fix it instead of just ```{Reset}```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work either

Comment: Ah okay I'm still learning so I will keep trying to suggest things to see if I do know how it works lol

Answer (score 1):

By default a button contained within a form will trigger a submit if the `type` attribute isn't specified.

Adding `preventDefault` to your `Reset` function should prevent this behaviour. Try adding `type="button"` to your reset button as this also prevents the default submit action.

Comment: Hi Jack, I insert preventDefault and type="button" but still don't work.
Thank you

Comment: Hi Mario, this could be something going wrong elsewhere in your code that you haven't included. [Here is a jsfiddle example of a basic react form with submit and reset functions](https://jsfiddle.net/g9hy6nj2/), perhaps this might help.